# Reading from .sql file located in Visual Studio repository

Tags: sql-server, powershell, visual-studio, git

A user.sql file which contains

USE [database]
GO
-- Legacy users cleanup
DROP USER IF EXISTS [dw];
etc...

is located at the repository: https://company.visualstudio.com/Database/_git/Azure?path=etc...

I have a powershell script running on a VM that restores the database and I need it to remove users from the newly restored db using the above user.sql file.

Is there a way to access the file directly from the .ps1 script, read the code from it and execute it?

If not, what would be the steps to make it work?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have permissions to clone this repo to the box from which you wish to execute your powershell script. In this case, assuming you have [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/) installed, your script would look like this:

```
Push-Location c:\path\to\repo
git pull
Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance sql1 -Database MyDb -File user.sql
```

If you do not have permissions to clone this repository, you can [create an azure pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline) to run this script if you have a friendly network admin to make sure your pipeline can run in a network segment with access to your SQL Server instance. Your pipeline.yaml file would look something like:

```yaml
jobs:
  - job: Run Script
    steps:
      - checkout: self
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: "inline"
          script: |
            Push-Location c:\path\to\repo
            $credential = [PsCredential]@{
                user="SqlUser"
                password="$(PIPELINE_SECRET)"
            }
            Invoke-DbaQuery `
                -SqlCredential $credential `
                -SqlInstance sql1 `
                -Database MyDb `
                -File user.sql
```

Comment: Thank you Peter for replying.

So it looks like that in any case I have to copy the DROP User script to a local folder in order to run it? I was hoping to be able to avoid that part.

Thanks again.